# jQuery to JavaScript: equivalent to $(".className tagName") selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I wonder what's the equivalent to this jQuery selector: `$(".className tagName")` in javascript?
Anyone can help me?
Thnaks in adcance.

Comment: `$(".className tagName")` is javascript

Comment: Yeah, but it's the jQuery syntax , i mean how to use like getElementById...to do the same?

Comment: Finnal solution: 1.canvas=document.querySelector(".className tagName") 2.canvas=$(".className tagName")[0] both will allow you call the canvas.getContext('2d').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll) you can use `document.querySelectorAll` with exactly same string selector. This function [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) collection (to be precise, NodeList collection) which you should not confuse with jquery collection though.

In any case, if, for some reason, you don't want to use jquery but want to use selectors intensively, the better solution will be to use some selector library like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com).

Comment: my case is the HTML is:<div class='className'><canvas></canvas></div>   Usually before we draw something with the canvas we use document.getelementbyid('canvasid') to get it, now the canvas is generated by a plugin and with no id

Comment: Thanks again,I worked it out by using document.querySelector, if I use document.querySelectorAll, error will happen.

Comment: @Wayou, most probably the error is due to you are expecting to get a single value, not a collection. You're welcome anyway)

Answer (score 0):

May be the traditional way but you could use **document.getElementByTagName** in javascript and then iterate through to get the exact element with matching class name.

Please the entire logic in one function and re-use this to get quick result without using jQuery. persisting the results of document.getElementByTagName() in global variable will give you a performance plus.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you,K D. I worked it out and paste the solution in the question comment, however, I think your way will also work.

Comment: Thanks, although you are working with canvas it means you need this script for all latest browser version only. this script will not work in older versions though, mine will work perfectly for all browsers surely:) Thanks for your recognition. happy coding, Vote up to your question :)

Comment: Oops! I forgot to consider the Compatibility of browsers. Thank you for reminding me.